# Insert array into MySql database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays, database

Here is an MultiAutocompleteTextView ,which gets the fav sports from the user ,and the the sports are now stored in the array ,i want to store this values in array in MySQL Database.

Here is my code:

```
   String[] str = {"Foot Ball", "Volley Ball", "Basket Ball",
            "Golf", "F1", "Marathon "};

    final MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.MyTags);

    mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str);
    mt.setThreshold(1);
    mt.setAdapter(adp);


    Button add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    assert add != null;
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = mt.getText().toString();

            if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
            }
            String sports[] = text.split(",");  // countries array will have all the countries entered in multiAutoCompleteTextView


                for (String s : countries) {
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: if you want to try save data in android device than use sqlite or Realm. If you want to save data on server than need to create web service for it and call web service for post data to server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have MySql database in the android, you can do that either on Sqlite on android or try using webservice which post data on the MySql server.

Comment: Yea with external Mysql server Only

Comment: You can write your webservice which takes the data as "post" or "get" parameter, when you receive data on that just post to the external mysql server. You can use any web based language for that. (Asp.net, PHP, Java etc. )

Answer (score 0):

To get the multiple split text from MultiAutoCompleteTextView and storing them in array and passing it to MySql from android:

```
 public class WorkNow extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String URL_ADD = "YOUR LINK";
public static String KEY_C="tags";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_now);

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);


    String[] str = {"India", "China", "Japan",
            "Nepal", "Italy", "Germany "};

    final MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str);
    mt.setThreshold(1);
    mt.setAdapter(adp);


    assert add != null;
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = mt.getText().toString();

            if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
            }
            String countries[] = text.split(",");  // countries array will have all the countries entered in multiAutoCompleteTextView

            for (final String s : countries) {
                Toast.makeText(WorkNow.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

                    ProgressDialog loading;

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkNow.this, "Adding...", "Wait...", false, false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                        super.onPostExecute(s);
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(WorkNow.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
                        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put(KEY_C, s);


                        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                        String res = rh.sendPostRequest(URL_ADD, params);
                        return res;
                    }
                }

                AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
                ae.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("YOUR_HOST_NAME", "USER_ID", "PASSWOR", "YOUR_DATABASE");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Getting values
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];



    //Creating an sql query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES ('$tags')";

    //Importing our db connection script


    //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Employee Added Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Add Employee';
    }

    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```